# Python Get row in a list by one of its attributes

Tags: python, list, get

so I got this list object which look something like:

```
[['String1', integer1], ['String2', integer2], ['String3', integer3], ['String4', integer4]]
```

I would like to get 'String1' by its integer value, without creating a new method just for that. Is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: If that is your data structure, no.

Comment: What should happen if two strings have the same integer value? If the answer is "that could never happen", consider switching to a dictionary.

Comment: mmmm that can happen, I expected to get a list with all the strings :)

Comment: I'm quite sure you'd be better of using a dictionary instead `a_dict = {'string1' : integer1, 'string2' : integer2}` then just loop through it using a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> seq = [['String1', 4], ['String2', 8], ['String3', 15], ['String4', 8]]
>>> result = [s for s, i in seq if i == 8]
>>> print result
['String2', 'String4']
```

---

Alternatively, if you have control over the format of your data structure, I suggest using a dictionary. Then getting strings is easy:

```
>>> d = {8: ['String2', 'String4'], 4: ['String1'], 15: ['String3']}
>>> print d[8]
['String2', 'String4']
```

Getting your data into that format in the first place is fairly simple, although I don't think you can do it cleanly in one line.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for s, i in seq:
...     d[i].append(s)
...
>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {8: ['String2', 'String4'], 4: ['String1'], 15: ['String3']})
```

Or

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for s,i in seq:
...     d.setdefault(i, []).append(s)
...
>>> print d
{8: ['String2', 'String4'], 4: ['String1'], 15: ['String3']}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a dictionary you have a lot more flexibility.

```
a_dict = {  'string1' : 6,
            'string2' : 76,
            'string3' : 765,}


for key in a_dict:
    if(a_dict[key] == 76):
        print('The number ' + str(a_dict[key]) + ' has a key name of ' + key)
```

And you can also have list as values if you need.